# procedure for executing any 'select' command

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a procedure that can execute any select in database and has table name and column names and where clause as input parameters

how can I develop that?

Comment: you'll need dynamic sql, but why doing this at all?

Comment: Look on Google for SQL Injection and why doing this is a bad idea (one of many reasons)

Comment: thanks for attention, it is just an exam question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an exam exercise, it's ok, but never do something like this in a real environment because of the [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) danger.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QueryExecution (
    @columns varchar(200),
    @tableName varchar(50),
    @conditions varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
    declare @query nvarchar(max);
    set @query = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ' + @conditions
    exec sp_executesql @query
END
```

Then call it like this:

```
exec QueryExecution 'Id, Description', 'MyTable', 'Id > 5 AND Description LIKE ''%some text%'''
```

*Note: if you need single quotes in your string, you must escape them by doubling them, like you can see in the `LIKE` clause.*